# undefined method 'avatar_changed?'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, carrierwave

This is the error I run into when I try to sign in or sign up in my heroku app. I recently added carrierwave and minimagick to my Gemfile, and tried to set things up for my users to upload avatar images; I seem to have something wrong!

There's another question about this on StackOverflow; the questioner answered their own question, saying that heroku had a different version of carrierwave than their local version. How would I find out what version of carrierwave heroku is running?

I haven't pushed my avatar changes to heroku yet, so I don't understand how carrierwave could be causing this problem, but apparently it is.

I'd appreciate any thoughts!

Comment: fyi heroku doesn't allow to upload images directry

Comment: do you have ```avatar``` field migrated to the table/db? And did you mount the the avatar_uploaded to the right file/model?

Answer (score 0):

If I may suggest an alternate way to handle your images...There is a Heroku addon called "Cloudinary" that works very well for your purposes. Please checkout this blog post on how to get it implemented
[Here](http://jose-at-devtheory.tumblr.com/post/104904986186/image-upload-storage-and-manipulation-for-your)